# BST implementation in Python

Tags: python, tree

I was asked to perform the following tasks at one of the technical interviews. I did the BST implementation in python. I think the solution passed all of the solution. I broke down the tasks in the following bulletin:

```
#  1) initilize the binary Search tree
#  2) Implement the "put" and "contains" methods with helper function
#  3) Test the "inOrderTraversal" method.
#  4) Add additional relevant tests


import unittest

class BST(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Node()

    def put(self, value):
        self._put(value, self.root)

    def _put(self, value, node):
        if node.value is None:
            node.value = value
        else:
            if value < node.value:
                if node.left is None:
                    node.left = Node()
                self._put(value, node.left)
            else:
                if node.right is None:
                    node.right = Node()
                self._put(value, node.right)

    def contains(self, value):
        return self._contains(value, self.root)

    def _contains(self, value, node):
        if node is None or node.value is None:
            return False
        else:
            if value == node.value:
                return True
            elif value < node.value:
                return self._contains(value, node.left)
            else:
                return self._contains(value, node.right)

    def in_order_traversal(self):
        acc = list()
        self._in_order_traversal(self.root, acc)
        return acc

    def _in_order_traversal(self, node, acc):
        if node is None or node.value is None:
            return
        self._in_order_traversal(node.left, acc)
        acc.append(node.value)
        self._in_order_traversal(node.right, acc)

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class TestBST(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.search_tree = BST()

    def test_bst(self):
        self.search_tree.put(3)
        self.search_tree.put(1)
        self.search_tree.put(2)
        self.search_tree.put(5)
        self.assertFalse(self.search_tree.contains(0))
        self.assertTrue(self.search_tree.contains(1))
        self.assertTrue(self.search_tree.contains(2))
        self.assertTrue(self.search_tree.contains(3))
        self.assertFalse(self.search_tree.contains(4))
        self.assertTrue(self.search_tree.contains(5))
        self.assertFalse(self.search_tree.contains(6))

        self.assertEqual(self.search_tree.in_order_traversal(), [1,2,3,5])

    def test_empty(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.search_tree.in_order_traversal(), [])

    def test_negative(self):
        self.search_tree.put(-1)
        self.search_tree.put(11)
        self.search_tree.put(-10)
        self.search_tree.put(50)
        self.assertTrue(self.search_tree.contains(-1))
        self.assertTrue(self.search_tree.contains(11))
        self.assertTrue(self.search_tree.contains(-10))
        self.assertTrue(self.search_tree.contains(50))

        self.assertEqual(self.search_tree.in_order_traversal(), [-10,-1,11,50])

    def test_dupes(self):
        self.search_tree.put(1)
        self.search_tree.put(2)
        self.search_tree.put(1)
        self.search_tree.put(2)
        self.assertTrue(self.search_tree.contains(1))
        self.assertTrue(self.search_tree.contains(2))

        self.assertEqual(self.search_tree.in_order_traversal(), [1,1,2,2])

    def test_none(self):
        self.search_tree.put(None)
        self.assertFalse(self.search_tree.contains(None))

        self.assertEqual(self.search_tree.in_order_traversal(), [])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: there are actually a few ways to accomplish this structure, I'd recommend searching around the internet and looking at all the other different implementations. I personally would construct something that acts like an object with the built in `__iter__` functionality, which would allow me to have the object act more like a collection/list and easily iterate it.

Answer (score 3):

**class Node**:

It is "strange" to have a `Node` with no value.  Consider removing the default `value=None`.

You never create a `Node` with an explicit "left" or "right" branch.  Consider removing these extra parameters from the constructor, and just assigning them to `None`.

Private members should be prefixed by an underscore.  Since no external entity should access the value, or the left or right branches, these should be renamed.

```
class Node:
   def __init__(self, value):
      self._value = value
      self._left = None
      self._right = None
```

---

`Node` is actually an internal detail of BST, so perhaps nest it as an inner class:

```
class BST:

   class _Node:
      def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value
        self._left = None
        self._right = None
```

---

Again, a node with no value is "strange".  It is much more common to represent an empty tree with as `root=None`, rather than `root=Node(None)`.

```
   def __init__(self):
      self._root = None
```

---

Your `put()` method calls `_put()`, which can call `_put()`, which can call `_put()` and so on.  In short, it is recursive.  There is no need to be recursive; you never need to return a value from a sub-call.  You are using tail-recursion, so the compiler/interpreter *might* simply jump back to the top of the function, instead of creating additional stack-frames.  Except [python doesn't do tail recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13591970/3690024), and you could get a stack overflow!

Instead, you can simply do the loop yourself:

```
   def put(self, value):

      new_node = BST._Node(value)

      if self._root:
         node = self._root

         while node:
            prev = node
            node = node._left if value < node._value else node._right

         if value < prev._value:
            prev._left = new_node
         else:
            prev._right = new_node

      else:
         self._root = new_node
```

---

Ditto for `contains()`.  Don't rely on tail-recursion, just create the loop yourself.

```
   def contains(self, value):
      node = self._root

      while node:
        if node._value == value:
           return True
        node = node._left  if  value < node._value  else  node._right

      return False
```

---

In-order traversal: building lists is so passé.  Generators can be much more efficient.  Starting with Python 3.3, we also get the cool new `yield from` syntax, to make them easier:

```
   def inorder(self):

      def _inorder(node):

         if node._left:
            yield from _inorder(node._left)

         yield node._value

         if node._right:
            yield from _inorder(node._right)

     if self._root:
         yield from _inorder(self._root)
```

If you want to return a list, and not the generator, you could simply pass the generator to the `list()` function.

```
   def inorder_list(self):
       return list(self.inorder())
```

---

Avoid polluting the global namespace.  I prefer my tests in a separate "xxxx_test.py" file, but for a single file solution, you can put the required imports and test classes in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

   import unittest, random

   class TestBST(unittest.TestCase):

      def test_random_lists(self):

         """Test a bunch of lists of various sizes, randomly"""

         for length in range(20):

            bst = BST()
            lst = [ random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(length) ]

            with self.subTest(lst=lst):

               for val in lst:
                  bst.put(val)

               lst.sort()

               self.assertEqual( bst.inorder_list(), lst)

   unittest.main()
```

---

Finally, documentation!  Use `"""docstrings"""`

Run `help(BST)` and look at the output.  Is everything documented?  Are there any unnecessary (ie, private) classes or methods exposed to the outside world?